# Tkinter Button Disabled Until Entry is Filled

Tags: python, tkinter, button, tkinter-entry

I am new to coding and I have been working in Tkinter trying to make a number guessing game.

I would like to have something where I have an entry box that the user can input a number and then a "Guess" button to submit the guess to see if the guess matches the secret number.

I would like to do something where the "Guess" button is grayed out and unclickable until a user inputs an appropriate datatype (int) into the entry box.

Is there any way I can do this? I know how to create entry boxes and buttons, I just don't know how to relate the two to have the button be gray when there is no input.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the entry text in a stringvar variable, add a lambda method and a callback function

```
def callback(sv):
    if sv == correct_answer:
        #here you can able the button
        btn.config(state=tk.DISABLED)   

sv = tk.StringVar()
sv.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=sv: callback(sv))
entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=sv)
```

Comment: what exactly is the lambda function doing in this code? sorry, I'm fairly new and it is a bit confusing.